# In XGBoost with a f1_score, is the iteration with a lower or higher score the better iteration?

Tags: precision-recall, boosting, f1

In the following XGBoost script the output states iteration 0 with score 0.0047 is the best score.  I would expect iteration 10 with score 0.01335 to be the better score?

Output

```
Start xgb.train
[0] train-F1_score:0.005977 eval-F1_score:0.00471
Multiple eval metrics have been passed: 'eval-F1_score' will be used for early stopping.
Will train until eval-F1_score hasn't improved in 10 rounds.
[1] train-F1_score:0.01074       eval-F1_score:0.006875
[2] train-F1_score:0.011652      eval-F1_score:0.008973
[3] train-F1_score:0.014231      eval-F1_score:0.010479
[4] train-F1_score:0.016044      eval-F1_score:0.010811
[5] train-F1_score:0.01645       eval-F1_score:0.010806
[6] train-F1_score:0.0179        eval-F1_score:0.011724
[7] train-F1_score:0.018575      eval-F1_score:0.011996
[8] train-F1_score:0.020258      eval-F1_score:0.011704
[9] train-F1_score:0.020238      eval-F1_score:0.012464
[10] train-F1_score:0.021241     eval-F1_score:0.01335
Stopping. Best iteration:
[0] train-F1_score:0.005977 eval-F1_score:0.00471
```

eval

```
def f1_eval(predt: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> Tuple[str, float]:
    y = dtrain.get_label()

    # convert the predicted values from {predt E R | 0<predt<1} to {0, 1} with a threshold of 0.5
    # all values less than 0.5 would be converted to 0 (False) and
    # all values equal or greater than 0.5 would be converted to 1 (True)
    predt_binary = np.where(predt > 0.5, 1, 0)
    return "F1_score", sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_true=y, y_pred=predt_binary)
```

param

```
param = {'max_depth': max_depth,
         'objective': 'binary:logistic',
         'disable_default_eval_metric': 1,
         'scale_pos_weight': scale_pos_weight,
         'max_delta_step': '2'}
```

train

```
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, watchlist,
                feval=f1_eval,
                evals_result=evals_result,
                early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
```

Comment: This F1 is looking pretty bad... I am not saying that some values are by definition good but not being able to scrape more than a F1 of 0.10 from a *predictive* model is worrying. (If we were doing inferential work it would be a different ball-game.) Maybe you should reconsider your modelling task.